# How to create a menu header for multiple webpages without copying the HTML for every webpage

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to output the same header for every webpage without having to copy the HTML for every one. How would I do this with javascript (I am not using PHP)? Could I use Angular JS ng-include function for this application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest question is:

### Have you tried it??

Please read [What topic can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

I'm answering since you already questioned. Yes, you can easily use Angular's `ng-include` here.

```
<html ng-app="foo">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ng-include src="'views/some/location/to/your/header.html'"></ng-include>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("foo", []);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**header.html**

```
<div class="header">
    <!-- Any content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use php for this - It makes page "templates" much easier. 
If you want to use JavaScript, you can use the jQuery `load()` function, like this

```
<script>$("#header").load("header.txt");</script>
```

Note: When using this make sure header.txt contains `<div id="header"></div>` tags around it, or you will override the header id

Header.txt should contain something like this

```
<div id="header">
  <!--This is where you put your header code-->
</div>
```

this way, if you want to change your header, all you need to do is change one file.